# One liner wanted: Create data frame and give colnames: R data.frame(..., colnames = c("a", "b", "c"))

Tags: r

Is there an easier (i.e. one line of code instead of two!) way to do the following:

```
results <- as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(c("SampleID_someusefulinfo.countsA" , "SampleID_someusefulinfo.countsB" , "SampleID_someusefulinfo.counts"), "\\.", n=2))
names(results) <- c("a", "b")
```

Something like:

```
results <- data.frame(str_split_fixed(c("SampleID_someusefulinfo.countsA" , "SampleID_someusefulinfo.countsB" , "SampleID_someusefulinfo.counts"), "\\.", n=2), colnames = c("a", "b"))
```

I do this *a lot*, and would really love to have a way to have this in one line of code.

/data.table works too, if it's easier to do there than in base data.frame/

Clarifying:

My expected output (which is achieved by running the two lines of code at the top **- AND I WANT IT TO BE ONE - THAT's IT!!!**) is a result data frame of the structure:

```
results
                       a      b
1 SampleID_someusefulinfo countsA
2 SampleID_someusefulinfo countsB
3 SampleID_someusefulinfo  counts
```

What I would like to do is:

1. CREATE the data frame from a matrix or with some content (for example the toy code of matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2) I provided in the first example I wrote)
2. SPECIFY ***IN THAT SAME LINE*** what I would like the column names of my data frame to be

Comment: @rawr My example was a toy, and I usually have a complex matrix in there, not something I'm specifying on the fly from some random numbers

Comment: `?matrix` was unhelpful?

Comment: @jaimedash I'm not trying to rename - I'm trying to create and name in one line!

Comment: gotcha, I was maybe being dense. but the edited version is clear

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `setNames()` around a `data.frame`

```
setNames(data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2)), c("a","b"))
#  a b
#1 1 3
#2 2 4
```

---

`?setNames`:

> a convenience function that sets the names on an object and returns the object

```
> setNames
function (object = nm, nm) 
{
    names(object) <- nm
    object
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU for this!!! It's not the most beautiful code (in the sense a novice reading it would probably not realise that you're creating the data.frame and setting the names simultaneously) - but I really love the fact that it's all in the same line - so definitely getting a lot of use in this neck of the woods :) !!!

Answer (score 5):

We can use the `dimnames` option in `matrix` as the OP was using `matrix` to create the data.

```
data.frame(matrix(1:4, 2, 2, dimnames=list(NULL, c("a", "b"))))
```

Or

```
`colnames<-`(data.frame(matrix(1:4, 2, 2)), c('a', 'b'))
```