# How to copy data.frame and change column names with a single expression?

Tags: r

Is there a way to achieve the following with a single expression?:

```
copy_of_df <- df
names(copy_of_df) <- c("some", "new", "column", "names", ...)
```

---

For example, starting with `df` as defined below

```
> set.seed(0)
> h <- 5
> (df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1:h, z = sample(LETTERS[1:3], h, replace = T)))
  x y z
1 1 1 C
2 1 2 A
3 1 3 B
4 1 4 B
5 1 5 C
```

...I can copy `df` and rename the *copy*'s columns, like this:

```
> copy_of_df <- df
> names(copy_of_df) <- c("P", "Q", "R")
> copy_of_df
  P Q R
1 1 1 C
2 1 2 A
3 1 3 B
4 1 4 B
5 1 5 C
```

Can the same copy + rename operation be achieved with a single expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
copy_of_df <- setNames(df,  c("P", "Q", "R"))
```

Comment: pah - you just beat me...

Comment: and the other answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36613366/5977215)