# concatenate on variables in R

Tags: r, concatenation

I have very simple and straightforward question:
When I execute `c("param_value" = "white")` I get:

```
param_value 
    "white"
```

When I have variables and want to execute `c(vfield = sfield)` I get:

```
 vfield 
"white"
```

I was trying to use `c(toString(eval(vfield)) = sfield)` but got erorr:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "c(toString(eval(vfield)) ="
```

I need the first output from second one. What else can I do?

Comment: What about `setNames(sfield, vfield)`? First argument is the object and second argument is the names you want to assign.

Comment: Question was asked for data frames here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613366/one-liner-wanted-create-data-frame-and-give-colnames-r-data-frame-colname/36613396

Comment: Ok. Superthanks! Sorry, not always it's clear how to search.